# How to stop Angular $rootElement.on('click') on ReactJS anchor tag?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, reactjs, angularjs-directive

I've AngularJS and ReactJS both running on same page.

But when I click on any ReactJS `<a>` tag, Angular's `$rootElement.on('click)` getting triggered and page redirects. 
I want to do few functionalities in ReactJS before page redirection.

I don't want to do changes in ReactJS, can anyone please suggest how I can handle this situation in Angular?

Comment: Are you talking about `#` routing in AngularJS ? `routeProvider` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution. In angular `run` we can simply write the below code block:

```
/**
 * We do not need to handle on-click handler if element belongs to reactJS.
 */
 $rootElement.off('click', '[data-reactid]');
```

So it won't handle any on-click scenario.

Answer (score 0):

From your question what you can do is, not to add `href` attribute in `<a>` tag. Rather pass the `routing` location to a function:

```
<a ng-click="redirect(your_routing_path)">Somethink</a>
```

and in controller:

```
$scope.redirect = function(your_routing_path){
     // do what React gotta do and then redirect
     $location.path(your_routing_path);
 }
```

Comment: `<a href="url" onClick={handler}>` are there in ReactJs, But AngularJs also triggers the Onlick, that's my problem

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.9/angular.js

Find `$rootElement.on('click', function(event) {` in above link

Comment: @HashirHussain : Yes, can you share your code and what business purpose you are trying to solve. May be I can suggest some workaround .

Comment: `let flag = false; //true in certain scenario
const onClick = (url, event) => {
 if (flag) {
  //I don't want to redirect
  event.preventDefault();
 }
};

<a
  href={href}
  onClick={onClick.bind(this, href)}
>
  {label}
</a>`